# Convergence of a Sequence of Probabilities

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, analysis

For each positive integer $k$, let $X_k$ be a binomial random variable with $X_k \sim \text{Bin}(k, p)$.

Show that the series $\sum_k \mathbb{P}(X_{2^k} \ge k)$ converges if $p < 1/2$ and diverges if $p \ge 1/2$.

I have been working this for a while (mostly trying to use Hoeffding's Inequality) but have come to a number of dead ends (note that the result might not be true; it is an hypothesis of mine).

If anybody out there sees something that I'm not seeing, please let me know...

Comment: I have a hunch that you can use stochastic dominance of binomial distributions to prove it. Namely, if we consider $X_1 \sim \text{Bin}(n_1, p)$ and $X_2 \sim \text{Bin}(n_2, p)$ such that $n_2 > n_1$, then $\mathbb{P}[X_2 \geq z] \geq \mathbb{P}[X_1 \geq z]$ for all $z$, and for some $z$ strict inequality holds. Try to use this to establish left and right bounds for the sum, then take limits and show that in one case, both bounds converge to finite value while in the other case they do  not.

Comment: Very strange task. $\frac{X_{2^k}}{k}\to +\infty$ a.s. for any $p>0$. And then $X_{2^k}>k$ i.o. with probability 1. And Borel - Cantelli Lemma implies that $\sum\mathbb P(X_{2^k}\geq k)=\infty$.